# How to move selected vertices along their normals in Edit mode by script?

Tags: python, vertices, normals

I'm trying to write code to move selected vertices along their normals in Edit mode. It seems like such a simple thing, but I cannot get it to happen.

I have searched this question and I keep finding:

```
for v in object.data.vertices:
    v.co += v.normal * distance
```

but this doesn't seem to do anything, by which I mean the vertices don't move and no error is thrown.
I have also found the use of bmesh, but this requires Object mode context to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Edit Mode use `bmesh`:

```py
scale = 0.1

import bmesh
from bpy import context as C

me = C.object.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

for v in bm.verts:
    if v.select:
        v.co += v.normal * scale

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
```

also for big meshes consider using `bm.select_history` to not iterate over all vertices unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1):

The code doesn't work in Edit Mode. In the modified version below, I temporarily switch to Object Mode to perform the edits, then switch back to the previous mode.

```py
import bpy

object = bpy.context.active_object
distance = 1

mode = object.mode
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

for v in object.data.vertices:
    if v.select == True:
        v.co += v.normal * distance
        
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode=mode)
```